# static variable shows different behavior in .dll/.lib

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

I am try to understand how static works in dll/lib, so I did the following test:

create three project:

```
1) libadd              //has an class Object and a template class Single<T>
2) libuseadd           //has a function useadd which will call 
                       // Single<Object>::instance in libadd
3) app                 // main() will call 
                       // Single<Object>::instance in libadd and
                       // useadd in libuseadd
```

//===========libadd=======================

```
//add.h
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

class __declspec(dllexport) Object
{
    public:
        Object():cnt_(0){}
        void speak()
        {
            std::cout<<"object:"<<cnt_++<<std::endl;
        }
    private:
        int cnt_;
        
};

template<typename T>
class __declspec(dllexport) Single
{
public:
    static T& instance()
    {
        static T t;
        return t;
    }

};

//add.cpp
#include "add.h"
```

//CMakelists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9 FATAL_ERROR)                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
set(PORJ_NAME libadd)
project(${PORJ_NAME})

add_library(${PORJ_NAME}
    add.h
    add.cpp
)
```

//===========libuseadd=======================

```
//useadd.h
#pragma once

__declspec(dllexport) void useadd();

//useadd.cpp
#include "useadd.h"
#include "add.h"

void useadd()
{
    Object& obj = Single<Object>::instance();
    obj.speak();
    
}
```

//CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9 FATAL_ERROR)                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
set(PORJ_NAME libuseadd)
project(${PORJ_NAME})

add_library(${PORJ_NAME}
    useadd.h
    useadd.cpp
)

target_include_directories( ${PORJ_NAME}
    PRIVATE 
        add/
    PUBLIC
)

target_link_libraries (${PORJ_NAME}
    PRIVATE
        bin/libadd.lib
)
```

//=====================main.cpp=====================

```
#include "add.h"
#include "useadd.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Object& obj1 = Single<Object>::instance();
    obj1.speak();
    
    useadd();

    return 0;
}
```

//CMakelists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9 FATAL_ERROR)                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
set(PORJ_NAME app)
project(${PORJ_NAME})

add_executable(${PORJ_NAME}
    main.cpp
)

target_include_directories( ${PORJ_NAME}
    PRIVATE 
        add
        useadd
    PUBLIC
)

target_link_libraries (${PORJ_NAME}
    PRIVATE
        libadd.lib
        libuseadd.lib
)
```

If the result is :

> object:0
>
> object:1

Then it means the static variable inside instance() function only has one instance (correct).

If the result is :

> object:0
>
> object:0

Then it means the static variable inside instance() function is **duplicate** (WRONG!)

I found the result is depended on whether the library is compiled as dll or lib.
When libadd and libuseadd all are compiled as dll, it even depended on whether the implemetaion of the instance function in .h or cpp. Say we have to change the of add.h/add.cpp to:

```
//when libadd/libuseadd all are dll, we have to use the codes below to 
//make it work correctly.
template<typename T>
class __declspec(dllexport) Single
{
public:
    static T& instance();
};
template  class   Single<Object>;

//add.cpp
#include "add.h"

#include "add.h"

template<typename T>
T& Single<T>::instance()
{
    static T t;
    return t;
}
```

[image]

I am wondering why

**updated (remove template and class Object):**

//===========libadd=======================

```
//add.h
#pragma once

#include <iostream>


class __declspec(dllexport) Single
{
public:
    static int& instance()
    {
        static int t = 0;
        int tmp = t++;
        return tmp;
    }

};

//add.cpp
#include "add.h"
```

//===========libuseadd=======================

```
//useadd.h
#pragma once

__declspec(dllexport) void useadd();

//useadd.cpp
#include "useadd.h"
#include "add.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void useadd()
{
    cout<< Single::instance() <<endl;
}
```

//===========main.cpp=======================

```
//main.cpp
#include "add.h"
#include "useadd.h"

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << Single::instance() << endl;
    useadd();
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Trying to export template types from a DLL is not generally sensible.  The client code can use any T that it desires, the DLL author cannot predict which ones it will use.  It is not forbidden, it *might* be useful in some cases.  A good example is `std::basic_string<>`, msvcp.dll exports the char and wchar_t specializations to implement std::string and std::wstring.  The static member inevitably turns it into a poison pill, don't do it.

Comment: @AlexF Thanks! I removed template and Class object. But you can see, I still can reproduce the strange behavior

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the clarification! Do you know why static variable behave different in dll and lib?

Comment: When you link the static library then every module gets its own copy and it is guaranteed to not work.  When you use the DLL then it *might* work since only the DLL module stores the variable in its data segment.   Emphasis on *might*, you have to guess at the T correctly.  This can only truly get to a good end when you have runtime support at the process level across module boundaries, arbitrating how variables are stored.  Features of VM implementations like the JVM and CLR, not of C++.

Comment: "When you link the static library then every module gets its own copy and it is guaranteed to not work. " in my test, if  both libadd and libuseadd are static, then it works, say, there is only one static variable instance. Do you know why?

Comment: Sigh.  If you have only one module (in other words, *only* link static libraries and don't use a DLL) then there can be only one copy of the variable and it seems to work.  The linker is powerless to provide that guarantee when a static library is linked into multiple modules.